# Google analytics tag manager e-commerce dataLayer not sent

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to send e-commerce events to google analytics using gtm (Google Analytics : Universal Analytics), this is my code

```
const loadGa = (next, retry) => {
    if (!retry) retry = 0;
    if (typeof ga === 'function') {
        return next(null);
    }
    if (retry > 10) return next(new Error('Can not load google analytics'));
    retry++;
    setTimeout(() => loadGa(next, retry), 500);
}

const addProductGa = product => {
    loadGa((err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        dataLayer.push({
            event: 'addToCart',
            ecommerce: {
                currencyCode: 'EUR',
                add: {
                    products: [{
                        name: product.name,
                        id: product.id,
                        price: product.acquisitionAmount / 100,
                        quantity: 1
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    })
}

const purchaseGa = (charge, product) => {
    loadGa((err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        dataLayer.push({
            ecommerce: {
                currencyCode: 'EUR',
                purchase: {
                    actionField: {
                        id: charge.id,
                        revenue: charge.amount
                    },
                    products: [{
                        name: product.name,
                        id: product.id,
                        price: product.acquisitionAmount / 100,
                        quantity: 1
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    })
}
```

For the example if I call the `addProductGa`

1. call to GTM
2. call to analytics
3. send basic tracking data

It seems that my e-commerce data are not sent, I can not see them in the network call to analytics server and I have no data on Google Analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can say:

- **By default `dataLayer.push` doesn't send data anywhere**, it just feeds the dataLayer. You need GTM triggers and tags to send the data, which brings me to the next point
- **Missing `event` key in some of your `dataLayer.push` calls** (eg `purchase`): I know you're following examples given in the [GTM ecom spec](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce) but IMO it's confusing: some of them show an event-based collections (with the `event` key set), others pageview-based collection (without the `event` key set). To simplify your setup you should:

  - [Always set the `event` key](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/add-the-event-key-to-datalayer-pushes/)
  - [Configure a trigger to handle those events](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679316?hl=en)
- **Full setup**: once you have an `event` property on all your dataLayer calls, you can generically track them all using a setup similar to the one shown below (**you should change the trigger to be a regex matching all your ecommerce events**, also don't forget to [enable Enhanced Ecommerce in the GA settings](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en#ee_datalayer)).

  [image]
- **If the issue persists** you should enable the [GTM preview/debug](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en) which will tell you why certain tags aren't firing and will show you the debug of the dataLayer values it contains
- **If GTM confirms tags are firing but you don't see GA tracking on the network**, you want to use the [Chrome GA debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) which will show you in details what's happening and potentially why hits are not sent.
- **Don't forget to publish GTM** once you have it all troubleshooted and working

Comment: `following examples given in the GTM ecom spec but IMO it's confusing` yes, so confusing

Comment: Yes their spec is inconsistent. What I do:
(1) all my triggers are event-based
(2) I use the Event Label to provide some debug info
(3) I attach eCommerce payloads to those events

That way I get the benefit of event tracking + debugging via the label and a consistent way to track Ecommerce. This also prepares you for `GA4` where everything is event based

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I ended up doing.